# Firebase / React Native - assertion failed

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a problem for which I didn't find much informations, I even read [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/promises) but I can't find the solution for this exception:

> Assertion failed: opt_onRejected should be a function. Did you pass opt_context as the second argument instead of the third?

here is my function which throws the exception:

```
  const {currentUser} = firebase.auth()
  const credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
   currentUser.email, 
   password)

  return (dispatch) => {
   currentUser.reauthenticate(credential) // 1. Re-authenticate
   .then(
     console.log("RE-AUTH"),
     currentUser.updateEmail(strEmail) // 2. Update email
     .then(
       console.log("MAIL UPDATE"),
       firebase.database().ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/`) // 3. Update profile email
        .update({email})
        .then(console.log("PROFILE UPDATE"))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
      )
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
    )
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
```

It works as it changes the email address but the exception shows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem, I added more `console.log()` to find out that my promise
answer was not handled correctly ([link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions)).

If anybody needs a working action for email change:

```
currentUser.reauthenticate(credential) // Re-authenticate
.then(() => {
  currentUser.updateEmail(strEmail) // Update email
  .then(() => {
    firebase.database().ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/`) // Update profile email
    .update({email})
    .then(() => 
      Alert.alert("Modification saved."),
      emailSaveSuccess(dispatch)
    )
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  })
  .catch(error => emailSaveError(dispatch, error))
})
.catch(error => emailSaveError(dispatch, error))
```